# How to draw this magnetic deflection?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

[image]

Hey everyone, I've made a huge progress on TikZ recently, Thanks for everyone who supported me on my last question, I really appreciate all of your hard work `<3`.

I want to draw this figure, but I faced some problems, with the position of angles, here's my code and its result (I've added the axes so I can write my article freely) :

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[smooth, ->] (0,0)--(5,0) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[smooth, ->] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above] {$\vec{i}$};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,1) node[left] {$\vec{j}$};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$\vec{v}_0$};
\node at (4.6,-1) {$\odot \vec{B}$};
 \draw[smooth] (3,-3) arc (0:90:3);
 \draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,-1.5) node[right]{$\vec{F}$};
 \node at (0,0) {$\odot$};
 \node[left] at (0,0) {$\vec{k}$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: using `tkz-euclide` package to draw the angles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to reproduce only your hand-drawn example. You can add the axes if you want, but the picture has enough labels as it is (IMHO).

The first step is to do some trigonometric computations, because we need to locate points S, I and I'. The rest is pretty straightforward, or so I think.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% parameters
\def\l{3}
\def\L{5}
\def\h{5}    % rectangle height
\def\R{3.5}  % radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sa{acos(\l/\R)}          % angle for point S
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sy{\R*sin(\Sa)}          % y for point S
\pgfmathsetmacro\Iy{\Sy-(\L-\l)/tan(\Sa)} % y for point I
\pgfmathsetmacro\Ix{\l-(\R-\Sy)*tan(\Sa)} % x for point I'
% coordinates
\coordinate (A)  at (\L,\R);
\coordinate (C)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (I)  at (\L,\Iy);
\coordinate (I') at (\Ix,\R);
\coordinate (O)  at (0,\R);
\coordinate (S)  at (\l,\Sy);
\coordinate (D1) at (\L,\h+0.5);  % Screen, top
\coordinate (D2) at (\L,\Iy-0.5); % Screen, bottom
% rectangle and magnetic field
\draw[fill=blue!10] (C) rectangle (\l,\h);
\foreach\i in {1,...,3}
{%
  \draw[blue] (\l*\i/4,0.6*\h+0.4*\R) circle (0.075*\l);
  \fill[blue] (\l*\i/4,0.6*\h+0.4*\R) circle (1pt);
}
% dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (O) node [left] {$O$} --++ (\L,0);
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (S) node[right] {$S$} -- (I');
% particles, path and vectors
\draw[thick,red]    (O) arc  (90:\Sa:\R) -- (I);
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) --++ (1,0)       node [above] {$\vec v_O$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) --++ (0,-1)      node [left]  {$\vec F_m$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (S) --++ (\Sa-90:1)  node [right] {$\vec v_S$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (S) --++ (\Sa+180:1) node [below] {$\vec F_m$};
\fill[shading=ball,ball color=green] (S) circle (2pt);
\fill[shading=ball,ball color=green] (O) circle (2pt);
\draw[blue,very thick] (D1) -- (D2);
% angles
\begin{scope}
  \clip    (A) -- (I') -- (S) -- cycle;
  \draw    (I') circle (0.4);
  \node at (I') [xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm] {$\alpha$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
  \clip    (C) -- (O) -- (S) -- cycle;
  \draw    (C) circle (0.4);
  \node at (C) [xshift=3mm,yshift=5mm] {$\alpha$};
\end{scope}
% dimensions
\draw[<->] (0,\h+0.25)  -- (\l,\h+0.25)  node[midway,above] {$\ell$};
\draw[<->] (0,\h+0.75)  -- (\L,\h+0.75)  node[midway,above] {$L$};
\draw[<->] (\L+0.25,\R) -- (\L+0.25,\Iy) node[midway,right] {$D_m$};
% labels
\fill (A)  circle (1pt) node     [above left] {$A$};
\fill (C)  circle (1pt) node     [left]       {$C$};
\fill (I)  circle (1pt) node     [below left] {$I$};
\fill (I') circle (1pt) node     [above]      {$I'$};
\node at (0.4*\l,0.4*\Sy)        [above]      {$R$};
\node at (\l-0.25,0.6*\h+0.4*\R) [blue]       {$\vec B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Great design, especially without using any fancy package. I'm so used to draw this kind of thing with `tkz-euclide` (with which code would be shorter), precisely to avoid all the calculations, so I'm impressed with your answer.

Comment: @SebGlav, thanks!! I usually like to make all the calculations and draw this way, in plain tikz (if possible). But yes, tkz-euclide would be easier.

Comment: I like it that way too. But for example, the idea of scoping a cirdle to draw the angles is clever on one hand but takes five lines instead of one, on the other hand (`angles` and `quotes` libraries save the day too).

Comment: very nice answer +1

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[smooth, ->] (0,0)coordinate(O)--(5,0)coordinate(x) node[above] {$x$};
            \draw[smooth, ->] (0,-3)coordinate(Q)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$};
            \draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above] {$\vec{i}$};
            \draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,1) node[left] {$\vec{j}$};
            \draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(1.5,0) node[ above right] {$\vec{v}_0$};
            \node at (4.6,-1) {$\odot \vec{B}$};
            \draw[smooth] (3,-3) arc (0:90:3);
            \draw[thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,-1.5) node[right]{$\vec{F}$};
            \node at (0,0) {$\odot$};
            \node[left] at (0,0) {$\vec{k}$};
            
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q](45:3){T} 

\tkzDrawPoints[size=4,fill=gray](Q,T) 
\tkzDrawSegment(Q,T)

\tkzDefLine[orthogonal =through T](T,Q)\tkzGetPoint{X}

\tkzDrawLine[color=red,add=0.41 and 0.2](T,X)

\tkzFillAngle[fill=blue!20, opacity=0.5](T,Q,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](T,Q,O){$\alpha$}
\tkzMarkAngle(T,Q,O)

\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=green!30](X,T,Q)

\tkzInterLL(T,X)(O,x)
\tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red](I)


\tkzFillAngle[fill=blue!20, opacity=0.5,size=1.5em](T,I,x)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.75](T,I,x){$\alpha$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1.5em](T,I,x)

\tkzFindAngle(T,I,x)    
\tkzGetAngle{angleTIx}
\edef\angleTIx{\fpeval{round(\angleTIx)}}
\node(J) [above right=of I]{The angle measurement is: \pgfmathprintnumber{\angleTIx} degrees};

        \end{tikzpicture}       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```