# how can I draw this pendulum?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I was recently interested on drawing this pendulum using TikZ, but I had some difficulties, here's what I want to get :

[image]

Here's my attempt and its result :

```
       \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[dashed, ->,smooth] (0,-3)--(0,4.5) node[right] {$z$};
 \draw[thick] (0,3)--(2,-2.5);
 \node[right] at (1,0.25) {$d$};
 \filldraw[black] (2,-2.5)circle(0.025);
 \draw[->] (2,-2.5)--(2,-3.5)node[left] {$\vec{P}$};
 \node[right] at (2,-2.5) {$G$};
 \filldraw[black] (0,3)circle(0.025);
 \draw[smooth, ->] (0,3)--(-0.17,3.8) node[left] {$\vec{R}$};
 \coordinate(o) at (2,-2.5);
\coordinate(b) at (0, -3);
\coordinate(a) at (0, 3);
\pic [draw=black!15!black,text=black,angle radius=13mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.3]{angle = b--a--o};
\draw[dashed] (2,-2.5)--(2,3)--(0,3);
\coordinate(c) at (2,3);
\pic [draw=black!15!black,text=black,angle radius=13mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.3]{angle = c--o--a};
\node[above] at (2,3) {$M$};
\node[left] at (0,3) {$O$};
\node[left] at (0,2.6){$(\Delta)$};
\pic [dashed ,draw=black!15!black ,angle radius=58.5mm,angle eccentricity=1.3]{angle = b--a--o};
\node[left] at (0,-2.8) {$G_0=O$};
\filldraw[black] (0,-2.85)circle(0.025); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me how to draw the body which is something like this :

[image]

Comment: something similar https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594075/how-to-draw-this-magnetic-deflection?rq=1

Comment: This looks good so far.  What difficulties are you having?  As far as drawing faster, it'd be possible to combine some commands to end up with fewer lines of code, but you're not really going to be able to beat one command per item in your output image.

Comment: @Teepeemm the body I couldn't draw it

Comment: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/physical-pendulum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the body using a smooth curve (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz)).

For instance, adding following lines to your `tikzpicture`:

```
\draw[dashed, red] (-1,3.3) -- (1,3) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (2.5,2) -- (3,-1) -- (2.5,-3) -- (1.5,-2.5) -- (0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw plot [smooth cycle, tension=.4] coordinates {(-1,3.3) (1,3) (1.5,2.5) (2.5,2) (3,-1) (2.5,-3) (1.5,-2.5) (0.5,0)};
```

gives this:

[image]

(red line to help the construction)

Comment: (+1) Thank you so much !